# OpenPose Installation Failure:Issue Resolved

Tags: cmake, opencl, cmake-gui, openpose

I have been trying to install the openpose framework for motoin tracking onto my Windows 10 PC which has a AMD Ryzen Pro 1700 Eight-Core CPU and a Radeon RX 580 GPU with 8GB of VRAM along with 16GB of Normal RAM. I have followed the instruction to compile from source so I can use it's associated python API but i've been struck with the above problem of the install failing due to the above error regardless if I have it set for OPENCL or CPU only ?

The full error log is linked Below:

```
:\openpose\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckSymbolExists.c(2,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/CL/cl.h': No such file or directory [D:\openpose\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_d0a4b.vcxproj]

  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_d0a4b.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_d0a4b.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue D:\openpose\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckSymbolExists.c



File D:/openpose/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:
/* */
#include <OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/CL/cl.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  (void)argv;
#ifndef CL_VERSION_1_0
  return ((int*)(&CL_VERSION_1_0))[argc];
#else
  (void)argc;
  return 0;
#endif
}
Determining if the include file pthread.h exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: D:/openpose/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
```

Could somebody please explain why the install is failing ?
The full log is linked here:
https://pastebin.com/r7ppEruG

Edit: I have resolved the issue, the inital problem was due to the fact that I had not restarted my computer having installed an OpenCL database meaning it wasn't being detected. That issue was resolved after it was updated. Following on another issue was that the models had failied to download, my investiagation showed the original domain that had at one point hosted the models had gone down.

Comment: For most problems, content of file `CMakeError.log` is not useful. Instead, show **output** of CMake which contains the error message.

Comment: Oh ok, here is the full output
https://pastebin.com/r7ppEruG

Comment: No, content of the files is not useful. We need the output of configuration process, when you run CMake. Most likely, exactly according to that output you decided that you have a problem.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/cDafFmkZ
Hi I've linked the cmake output above

Comment: I have fixed the issue with regards to open CL but have confronted a new issue where Cmake Claims to be missing the variable BOOST_FILESYSTEM_LIB_RELEASE

Comment: So, your question is about the line "CMake Error at cmake/Utils.cmake:23 (file):" and following message? Please, add this message into the **question post** and update the title appropriately. Note, that on Stack Overflow all relevant information should be in the **question post** itself; **links** are **not sufficient**.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the source of the error, it seems the opensource links for getting cafe installed are dead and this also applies to the ones used by camke. Until the link is live again or fixxed the problem will persits.
The link used to get openCL installed is dead.
http://posefs1.perception.cs.cmu.edu/OpenPose/3rdparty/windows/caffe_opencl_2018_02_13.zip